# PHP Select SQL view no output

Tags: php, sql, timeout, view, mysql-connect

I creating a php file that pulls a view from an SQL database.  Can someone let me know why this isn't working?  It seems to be timing out.  I am not getting a connection error, either.  Thank you in advance.

```
<?php       
require ('mysqli_connect.php');         

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM testview ;";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql);

     // Check connection if ($dbc->connect_error) {
          die("Connection failed: " . $dbc->connect_error); } 

     $result=mysqli_query($sql);

     if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         echo "<table><tr><th>userID</th><th>first_name</th></tr>";
         // output data of each row
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr><td>".$row["userID"]."</td><td>".$row["first_name"]."</td></tr>";
}
  echo "</table>"; } else {
  echo "0 results"; }

} 
$dbc->close(); 

?>
```

Here is the connection file

```
<?php
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'root');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'Test');

// Make the connection:
$dbc = mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL: ' );
?>
```

Comment: For starters your mixing mysql and mysqli which doesn't work. Switch everything to mysqli. And the connection seems to be both $conn and $dbc?

Comment: shoot, that is just a typo.  I cannot get mysqli_connect to work on my computer, so I am switching it to mysql_connect.  This is just a test.  I will correct that typo.

Comment: Show your connection code if you are getting connection error

Comment: I am not getting a connection error. @anantkumarsingh.  I am just not getting any output

Comment: try to remove second mysql_query code and put mysqli_* every where?

Comment: How is your testview defined?

Comment: That die() statement in your main code would seem to end everything.

Comment: What's with all the '>' characters at the beginning of the lines?

Comment: Wouldn't I then get a connection error stating "Connection Failed" @BigScar

Comment: @PeterBowers, It's just because i copied it off my text editor

Comment: Put an `echo "A<br />\n";` before the mysql_query and `echo "B<br />\n";` after it - then let us know which gets printed.

Comment: @Kripos Your connection seems to be $dbc, not $conn. And there are stray {} in a couple of places in your code that don't make sense.

Comment: Code as it stands wouldn't even compile. You have a '}' (end of line 7) without a matching opener. Do you have error messages turned on to see what syntax errors you're getting?

Comment: @Peter Actually 2 "}".

Comment: @BigScar- Sorry for the typos.  I have been making a lot of changes to my connection file and the code.  Let me correct.

Comment: Try taking the die() out of your main code. It needs to be inside a conditional statement or it will stop you dead in your tracks every time.

Comment: You haven't effectively moved away from mysqli -- you are still using OOP syntax and mysql_* functions don't even support OOP syntax as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this a go. you were using mysqli and mysql in the same document. this somtime causes issues.

```
require_once ('mysqli_connect.php');         

$q = "SELECT * FROM testview";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

//there was no real need to check the connection, you should be doing this in your connection script.

//you where using 'mysqli' above and 'mysql' below. 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

if ($r) {

   echo "<table><tr><th>userID</th><th>first_name</th></tr>";

     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){

         echo "<tr><td>" . $row["userID"] . "</td><td>" . $row["first_name"] . " " . $row["last_name"] . "</td></tr>";
     }
         echo "</table>"; 
} else {
         echo "0 results"; 
}

close($conn);
```

Comment: Not sometimes - mysqli and mysql are like oil and water. They just don't mix.

Comment: Thank you @ballbern.  After made your suggested changes, it worked.

Comment: @balibern just remove the first $row to include all returned data

Answer (score 0):

You do not have error messages turned on. Therefore when you are getting syntax errors and etc. they are not showing up and you are assuming a time-out.  OR perhaps since you have a non-existent function in your die() call maybe it gets confused trying to die but not able to die.

Before you euthanize your code, turn error messages on. Your code will thank you.

Oh, and change

```
die("Connection failed: " . $dbc->connect_error);
```

to

```
die("Connection failed: " . mysql_error($dbc));
```